# AWS | Data pull from SFTP

Tags: amazon-s3, sftp, data-ingestion

I'm planning to write a data pipeline that pull the data from on-prem SFTP server to S3. How can I achieve this? I am interested in AWS specific services only.

Comment: This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

AWS provides a native way to transfer your files from any on-prem servers to s3 directly **AWS Transfer Family**. It is a multi-AZ, highly available, massively scaling SFTP interface for S3. With this basically you will running a cron or scheduler process to transfer the on prem SFTP server files into S3 buckets via AWS SFTP server.

> Documentation link - [AWS Transfer Family](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/how-aws-transfer-works.html)

The only catch here is the pricing for it. It is little higher on the cost. There are third party tools available with lesser price like **SFTP Gateway for AWS** which can be found in AWS marketplace

> Documentation link - [SFTP Gateway](https://www.thorntech.com/products/sftpgatewayaws/)

Lastly, if your use case is simple with only very few SFTP uploads a day, solution would be to use T2/T3 EC2 instances and a cronjob to run the custom developed pipeline script that pulls data from on prem SFTP server.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you have a key file to connect to your AWS instance, you can use scp to specify it in the file transfer command:

```
scp -i ~/.ssh/<aws_key>.pem <path_to_source_file> <aws_user>@<aws_ip>:<destination_path>
```